# Idiomatic way to use filter()

Tags: for-loop, filter, rust

When using `filter`, you receive a reference because [`filter` does not return ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/iterators.html). However `iter()` already references what you are iterating over so you get code that looks like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<(bool, i32)> = Vec::new();
    vec.push((true, 1));
    vec.push((false, 2));
    vec.push((true, 3));
    for &(_, x) in vec.iter().filter(|&&(exists, _)| exists) {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

That seems like a lot of `&` to me. Is this considered the idiomatic way to implement `filter()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short [yes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter). Although in your particular example you can use `into_iter` to get an iterator that does return ownership.